# JavaScript - setTimeout doesn't work in a for loop

Tags: javascript, settimeout

for university I have to create a javascript slideshow. 
I use the function setTimeout( "other function", timeout).
My problem is that using this function recursive ( slideshow() ) works but when I try use it in a for loop ( altSlideshow() ) nothing happens.

```
// this one works
function slideShow() {
    nextImg();
    setTimeout(slideShow, timeOut); //Angabe Timeout in Millisekunden
}

// this one doesn't work
function altSlideshow(){
    for(var x = 0; x <= 4; x++){
       setTimeout(nextImg(), timeOut);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems here :

- you pass `nextImg()` instead of the function `nextImg`
- you schedule all the timeouts for the same instant (the delay you pass is computed from the time of execution of the loop)

Change

```
setTimeout(nextImg(), timeOut);
```

to

```
setTimeout(nextImg, timeOut*(x+1));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to pass a reference to the function, rather than using the returned value:

```
function altSlideshow(){
    for(var x = 0; x <= 4; x++){
       setTimeout(nextImg, timeOut);
    }
}
```

Also, as dystroy mentions, you should make use of `x` to generate a unique timeout for each iteration.